# Can I execute query using two databases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've never tried this but I'm currently considering database design and wanted to know if its possible to run SQL Queries against two separate MySQL Databases on the same or different Server/Cluster?

Also what are speed issues with these types of configurations (cross database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, why not, you can use same query for different MySql Database, all you need is their authentication to access that particular database. I mean to say, the `username` and `password` for each database. Like in `php` we use these script to connect our database.

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';  //server       
$dbname   = 'myphp';   //database
$username = 'root';             //username
$password = '';                 //password
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');
mysql_select_db($dbname) or DIE('Database name is not available!');
?>
```

So, you need to create different connection script and change them accordingly. As you see,in my connection script `hostname` is the server location (generally it is an IP address, where your server is), currently it is set to `localhost` (you can change it to 127.0.0.1), since my computer itself serve as a server. So, you need to change the server details only (if database, username and password are same for all).

Now, coming to next part of your question i.e. speed issue, so i would say, it depends on the server, how much time it takes to respond. There are many factors (like number of user, server respond time and etc) that affects the speed issue.

Comment: could you do this if the databases were on different servers? Query Speed issues?

Comment: that is what i'm saying, just look my connection script, in which there is server location (generally it is an IP address of server).